# How can I add sub tabs in existing qtabwidget?

Tags: c++, qt

I am new to Qt and developing an application using this.
I have added 5tabs using addTAb().
Now I want to add sub tabs in existing qtabwidget.... How can I achieve so??? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Add the subtab to the tab's `layout`. Use:

```
// Get the tabpage for tabnumber
Widget* tabpage = tabwidget->widget(tabnumber);
// Add QTabWidget to tabpage's layout
tabpage->layout()->addWidget(new QTabWidget());
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add another QTabWidget inside a Tab and use `int QTabWidget::addTab(QWidget * page, const QString & label)`.